# Side menu obscures footer CSS / HTML / JADE

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

I'm using side menu from here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu in my node.js application (view engine: jade) - however it doesn't matter because you can simply convert code from html to jade here http://html2jade.org/

At first glance it looks fine:
[image]

But if you scroll down, then we have problem because side menu obscures footer, what you can see below:
[image]
Also there is white space above menu, however the most important problem is with footer. How can I solve this? For example here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu side menu is in frame, so maybe this is good solution, but i don't know how can i do the same thing in my case.

By the way this is how looks like my view:

```
extends layout //default layout with header and footer

block content
    .row
      .side-menu
        nav.navbar.navbar-default(role='navigation')
          .navbar-header
[... the rest of the code]
```

**@EDIT
Here is an example on fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/c28n2dhj/

Comment: roughly speaking menu has position fixed and height:100% it's bound to overlap everything vertically with such properties. for more analysis you'd better provide a fiddle or the whole code for reading.

Comment: Ok, check edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, position fixed of the side menu overlayed footer, while the space from the top that you had noticed is due to the absence of a defined TOP property. This space = header height+header margin-bottom.

The layout is somewhat tricky, because you want header and footer, where a basic layout "Admin side menu" is not supposed to have. I suggest the following - side menu has top:0; and header/footer have bigger z-indexes they overlay this side menu and have non transparent backgrounds. 
Then we offset the menu items from the top with margin-top:52px (height of the header)

```
        .side-menu {
            top:0;
        }

        .navbar.navbar-top {
          position:relative;
            z-index: 10;
          margin-bottom:0 !important;
        }


        .side-menu .navbar {
          margin-top:52px;
        }

        .side-menu.affix .navbar {
          margin-top:0;
        }

        .footer-container {
          position:relative;
          z-index:10;
          background:#ffffff;
        }
```

In order to keep top menu item closer to the top of the window on scrolling we can use Affix component from Bootstrap (its class .affix to be precise) to move the margin-top of menu items in the side menu.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c28n2dhj/2/)**

**[DEMO w/Sticky footer](https://jsfiddle.net/ux108xm7/2/)**

P.S. I didn't look what happens exactly in mobile version, i believe there was some mess before my code with menu lis overlaping each other.

Comment: It's almost done. But check this https://jsfiddle.net/ux108xm7/ position of footer is dependent of text. Is there any solution for this? Maybe footer only under text or always attached to the bottom?

Comment: then apply sticky footer technique,as written https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ . I updated Demo link

Comment: Thank you, by the way why if I click anywhere then Brand is hiding? I had to change `data-offset-top="1"` (was `"0"`) and is fine. Have I done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

> .navbar-footer 
>   After  .navar-header

I think that should solve the problem

Comment: Hm? Where? Did you try on my fiddle example?

Comment: Nope, i haven't tried. But this could make your and footer at Delft

Comment: ** header and footer at left side, so that your main page footer would have centre aligned

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have enough experience and I'm not sure what should I do